# Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'arrayOf'

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I am migrating code from Swift 2 to Swift 4. The following code works well in Swift 2 but gives error in Swift 4:

```
let unorderedComments = try? json.arrayOf("comments", type: Comment.self)
```

Error:

> Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'arrayOf'

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

EDIT:
I have used [Freddy](https://github.com/bignerdranch/Freddy) library for JSON Parsing

Comment: Not a lot of context to go on here, but that may be json.array(of: "comments"....) now

Comment: Did you run the Xcode Swift converter?

Comment: what is `json`'s object type?

Comment: what is `json` here? and have you used any specific library here?

Comment: @MikeTaverne yes I used it to convert the code from Swift 2 to Swift 4

Comment: @staticVoidMan I have used Freddy library for JSON Parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'arrayOf'

Error clearly states that the object `JSON` does not have any `arrayOf` method.

*You later stated that this object is a [Freddy JSON](https://github.com/bignerdranch/Freddy) object. (You should have added this to your question in the beginning itself)*

Now in your case, you are migrating code from Swift v2 to v4. That's a huge leap so in such cases when one hits a snag, the first thing one should do is check the documentation, and particularly in your case, see if there is an `arrayOf` method or if it has changed, and what similar options are now available.

---

Anyways, as per the documentation, [Freddy](https://github.com/bignerdranch/Freddy) has a `getArray(at:)` which I believe has, over time, replaced `arrayOf(_:type:)`.

The following should fix this issue:

```
let unorderedComments = try? json.getArray(at:"comments")
```

NOTE: The above function takes a variadic parameter; i.e. it can take multiple strings in case you want a, sort of, path.
Something like `json.getArray(at:"rootKey",1,"nestedKey")` would be similar to `json["rootKey"][1]["nestedKey"]`

---

PS: Since you are upgrading from v2 to v4, this won't be the only error to deal with.
Just follow the same idea and fix your other errors.
If you get stuck, we are here to help
:)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have an array of comments (which contain dictionary).

The following should get you started:

```
var results: [String: AnyObject]? = nil
do {
    results = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
    // Now try to extract data:
    guard let results = results else {
        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to get any results"]
        let error = NSError(domain: "<whatever error name>", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo)
        return error
    }
    // get comment
    guard let dictionary = results[Parse.JSONResponseKeys.<Responsekey>] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to get list"]
        let error = NSError(domain: "<whatever error name>", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo)
        return error
    }
    // process the array
    if dictionary.count > 0 {
        // get the 1st element
        comment = Comment.init(dictionary: dictionary.first!)
        // if you know you have more than one... you can put this in a loop
        return comment
    } else {
        return null
    }
} catch {
    //How ever you want to catch error
}
```